# Limit to number of images scraped from web site?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using Selenium and BeautifulSoup in python3 to scrape images off a web page. I am using Selenium because the site content is dynamically-generated and requires a login. All is working as planned....except that I am only downloading 101 images out of a possible 300. Here is the relevant code:

```
source = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
avatar_images = soup.find_all('img', 'avatar__image' )
print(len(avatar_images)) # 101

urls = [img['src'] for img in avatar_images]

for index, url in enumerate(urls):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url).content
        with open("img_" + str(index) + ".jpg", 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response)
        print("Downloading '%s'" % (url))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print("%s '%s'" % (e, url))
```

I am wondering why the avatar_images array is only collecting the first 101 images that meet the criteria when all 300 images are of class 'avatar__image'. Could it be because the image urls are quite long? For example, here is a selection of lines from the print statement above:

```
Downloading 'https://pingboard-production.s3.amazonaws.com/user/avatars/GqcEiAOQ6SiHpLBrpAit_8a8739f9793af0363c2b16cb92c7b75135d812cf20c764d2cd23fd1adf2ee493.jpg'
Downloading 'https://pingboard-production.s3.amazonaws.com/user/avatars/2PA7hBWiSNSNsrkpHave_8a8739f9793af0363c2b16cb92c7b75135d812cf20c764d2cd23fd1adf2ee493.jpg'
Downloading 'https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/AchUBPpbtR12UdA8r3ilwz/security=policy:eyJleHBpcnkiOjIxNTAxMzIzMDYsImNhbGwiOlsicmVhZCIsImNvbnZlcnQiXSwiaGFuZGxlIjoiR3hIR2lGN1FJS3ZIYzFSS1Q0dHcifQ==,signature:83447afe4180229b9d3c8e24cd22a1b99476134bdc4ae6429971a4115e0e8616/resize=w:300,h:300,fit:crop,align:faces/rotate=d:exif/GxHGiF7QIKvHc1RKT4tw'
Downloading 'https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/AchUBPpbtR12UdA8r3ilwz/security=policy:eyJleHBpcnkiOjIxNTk0ODQ3NzAsImNhbGwiOlsicmVhZCIsImNvbnZlcnQiXSwiaGFuZGxlIjoicjhLaW5tbnRUOEI1bUwwY1VNancifQ==,signature:62995975dd025983b87cea7530b145f1fcbb89cb33376512381dee49de603fdb/resize=w:300,h:300,fit:crop,align:faces/rotate=d:exif/r8KinmntT8B5mL0cUMjw'
```

All of these initial 101 images have successfully downloaded in order, but never any more than that. Could I be encountering a limit on the number of characters in the avatar_images array?

All 300 images are of similar format and individually load through their urls. The last image to download comes from this element:

```
<img class="avatar__image" width="300" height="300" data-bind="attr: { src: avatarUrl, alt: name }" src="https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/AchUBPpbtR12UdA8r3ilwz/security=policy:eyJleHBpcnkiOjIxNjEwMzc2NDgsImNhbGwiOlsicmVhZCIsImNvbnZlcnQiXSwiaGFuZGxlIjoiWlcxcGRhMW5TV0NKZ0dkSnlUaU0ifQ==,signature:8e61a789abcef404ce614e4d4e4ff583dd5bf24bde78dc616fd5c73e85fdbdf7/resize=w:300,h:300,fit:crop,align:faces/rotate=d:exif/ZW1pda1nSWCJgGdJyTiM" alt="">
```

and the first to not download has this element:

```
<img class="avatar__image" width="300" height="300" data-bind="attr: { src: avatarUrl, alt: name }" src="https://pingboard-production.s3.amazonaws.com/user/avatars/UM4IhNRzeanP6DH8rS8w_8a8739f9793af0363c2b16cb92c7b75135d812cf20c764d2cd23fd1adf2ee493.jpg" alt="">
```

**EDIT** I checked the value of `soup` and realized that it only contains 101 images. The dynamically-populated site must be restricting the number of image elements to this number and populating the rest upon scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web-page probably uses something like https://infinite-scroll.com/. So to scroll down to the bottom of the content with selenium you can use:

```
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
```

Then you need to wait for the page to load. Setting the window size to a large value may help you as the page may load more items. You may need to scroll multiple times depending on the web-page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver  
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1680, 1050)
url = ("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=test&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPiZCr6N_cAhVCJBoKHdzhDBwQ_AUICygC&biw=1680&bih=944")
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
# Wait for page to load.
time.sleep(5)
source = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
...
```